# How to kill long running queries through Pro*C?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-pro-c

We are interacting with DB though Pro*C. We want to find out the queries which are taking the longest time through Pro*C.

Is there a way to find out long running queries in Pro*C?

Comment: What is a "Pro *C"? can you give a link to website of this program? What is your db

Comment: Pro*C is a pre-processor for embedded oracle. It allows to write directly SQL queries in the C code. The pre-processor then replace them with the code necessary to make the Oracle API calls.

Comment: This is not about `C` and the `pro` tag really says nothing about anything. Tags changed.

Answer (score 1):

By testing the queries outside of C, with toad for instance?
Or by counting the time they take with the normal C functions for timers?

Your question is too vague to give a specific answer.

Answer (score 1):

The Pro*C programs should be readily identifiable in V$SESSION through the PROGRAM column. I'd go further and explicitly set MODULE through DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO, which will allow you to track down individual SQLs in V$SQL.

Once you instrument your code, it becomes much easier to use the diagnostic facilities such as trace or any extras you may have paid for with the Diagnostics or Tuning packs

Comment: well gary isn't there any specific function or mechanism provided by Pro*C or Oracle that can be used
What i have seen is that everytbody is talking about 'Ctrl+C' combination which by all means is strictly wrong to do. Isn't there any timeout function that can be used to timeout a query after , say , 10 seconds and proceed with the nexty query.
Also, I understood nothing out of what you said in your answer.
Tell me some robust solution if possible.

Answer (score 1):

oracle enterprise manager allows you to look at the running queries, and let's you look at the explain plan.